# Getting the last known location with google play services

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I've been going through the android developer docs to try and work out how t get current location, specifically https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

When I create a new project in android and select the Map template there is code in the onCreate method and then there is also a onMapReady method.

Firstly, just to confirm is the code below putting the map on the screen? And if so is onMapReady just a method then to allow manipulating the map?

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) etSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map); mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

In the documentation re: get the current location there is info re: building to the GoogleApiClient eg

```
// Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
}
```

The other methods that are specified in the docs are onStart, onStop and onConnected. That all makes sense but to make a very basic get current location app do I still use the SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) .... from within onCreate to generate the map? And is the onMapReady function still necessary? And where is the best place to create an instance of the GoogleApiClient?

On the subsequent docs page there is also info about getting the current location settings once connected with

```
 LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
     .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
```

But I just wasn't sure where that should be defined.

Finally in the Map template in Android Studio the default class is defined as:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
```

But in the google docs it's defined as:

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener

Does it matter which Activity the class extends?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used pre-defined Map Activity.You can get your last known and current location thorough it.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            mLastLocation = location;
            if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
            }

            //Place current location marker
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            //move map camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

            //stop location updates
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
            // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
        }
    }
}
```

Allow network state permission and location permissions in Android Manifest

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. My question is whether onLocationChanged ever gets called and from where it gets called. In the android docs there is a section re:

Comment: Hi Avinash. Thanks for that. My question is whether onLocationChanged ever gets called and from where it gets called. In the android docs  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html it goes through the use of LocationManager & LocationListener - but this obviously isn't used in your (or my) code.  I also just wasn't sure exactly what this was doing:  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this); Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is only to get the current location of the user, then you need not use MapActivity, you can rely on LocationServices and ask for **getLastLocation** .Here is the below sample code which serves your purpose.

```
  // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
}
```

Since you would have implemented the listeners of GoogleApiClient, hence you can ask for location as shown in below code:

```
     @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            startLocationUpdates();
        }

        protected void startLocationUpdates() {
            Log.d(TAG, "startLocationUpdates--> Start Location Updates");
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

        public void stopLocationUpdates() {
            Log.d(TAG,"stopLocationUpdates--> Stop location updates");
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);
            stopService();
        }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " +
                connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged--> Location is " + location.toString());
        mCurrentLocation = location;
    }
```

Also, if you want to keep track of location after a regular interval, you create an object of **locationRequest** like this from **OnCreate**(where you created object of GoogleApiClient):

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    Log.d(TAG,"createLocationRequest--> Create Location Request");
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000); //UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MS
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000); //FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MS
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
}
```

Here is the startLocation update method:

```
 protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    Log.d(TAG, "startLocationUpdates--> Start Location Updates");
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

I hope this answers your question, kindly mark this as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you explain please for the startLocationUpdates method how the map is actually rendered? I assume that  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this); will get the updated location but how then does that get put on the map?

Comment: Hi Avinash. Thanks for that. My question is whether onLocationChanged ever gets called and from where it gets called. In the android docs  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html it goes through the use of LocationManager & LocationListener - but this obviously isn't used in your (or my) code.  I also just wasn't sure exactly what this was doing:  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this); Cheers.